# App crashing whenever trying to save SharedPreferences

Tags: android, json, android-sharedpreferences, gson

I've got an app which works fine until I press one of two buttons, both of which save my current custom class which stores four `ArrayList<String>`'s as a JSON file.

Below is my code to load and save my JSON file to/from SharedPreferences:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = myPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
    StudentArray obj = gson.fromJson(json, StudentArray.class);

    studentsFirstNames = obj.studentFirstName;
    studentsLastNames = obj.studentLastName;
    studentsCourses = obj.studentCourse;
    studentsYearsOfStudy = obj.studentYearOfStudy;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    StudentArray example = new StudentArray(studentsFirstNames, studentsLastNames, studentsCourses, studentsYearsOfStudy);
    String json = gson.toJson(example);
    prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

Logcat crash log

```
04-26 21:58:38.985 14971-14971/com.adam_smedley.moduleenrollment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.adam_smedley.moduleenrollment, PID: 14971
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.adam_smedley.moduleenrollment/com.adam_smedley.moduleenrollment.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4089)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:344)
    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:493)
    at com.adam_smedley.moduleenrollment.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:89)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

alright, so it seems that my ArrayList's are null object references as I cannot add another string to them or get .size()

Can anyone see any problems with the declaration below

```
static ArrayList<String> studentsFirstNames;
studentsFirstNames = new ArrayList<String>();
studentsFirstNames.add("John");
```

and with the call inside my AddNewStudent activity

```
    MainActivity.studentsFirstNames.add(firstName);
```

which should access the static ArrayList studentsFirstNames inside the Main Activity and add a single string, firstName, to the ArrayList.

onActivityResult code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    ListAdapter enrollmentAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, studentsFirstNames, studentsLastNames, studentsCourses, studentsYearsOfStudy);
    ListView studentsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.StudentsListView);
    studentsListView.setAdapter(enrollmentAdapter);
}
```

It is definitely caused by the onResume() and onPause() code above, as I've since commented it out and my app works but it doesn't save anything so I don't have any data persistence.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, could you only post the code which is involved when you finishEnrollment and saveEnrollment.  Just edit the question. Otherwise you may not ever get any help.

Comment: Where is your inActivityResult code, that's where the crash is happening, can you share it?

Comment: @MidasLefko the onActivityResult code?

Comment: You should not access the `studentsFirstNames` from another Activity. You need to handle the `add` in `onActivityResult`. `AddNewStudent 
` activity musn't know what the MainActivity doing.

Comment: According to the stacktrace one of the following lists is null in onActivityResult: studentsFirstNames, studentsLastNames, studentsCourses, studentsYearsOfStudy. You should debug to figure out which and why

Answer (score 0):

There is probability that you're getting invalid  `StudentArray` in your `onResume` method. So, you need to check for null or exception when you're getting the object with gson. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  SharedPreferences myPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String json = myPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
  try {
    StudentArray obj = gson.fromJson(json, StudentArray.class);
    if (obj != null) {
      studentsFirstNames = obj.studentFirstName;
      studentsLastNames = obj.studentLastName;
      studentsCourses = obj.studentCourse;
      studentsYearsOfStudy = obj.studentYearOfStudy;
    } else {
      // obj is null. You need to do something here.
    }
  } catch (IllegalStateException | JsonSyntaxException exception) {
    // there is something wrong when parsing the json
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the case. In Logcat I get a fatal exception on trying to get 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference. I don't have any .size() calls of my own so is it something done by the onResume function when the other activity finishes?